# Characterization of a "Jacobian pair" member 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the ring ${R}$ of Puiseux series in $Y$ with coefficients in the ring $\mathbb{C}((X^*))$ of Puiseux series in $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$; $F \in R$ is said to be a member of a Jacobian pair iff there is $G \in R$ such that $J(F,G)=1$ (where $J(F,G) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$
is the determinant of the Jacobian of $F, G$ with respect to $X,Y$.)

In http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1115 , there appears a surprising equivalence of this property, namely: $F \in R$, not a constant is a member of a Jacobian pair iff (-1,-1) is not in $supp( (F-c)^a)$ for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and any $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

My question is, has this sort of characterization appeared before?, i.e.: the condition on the supports as lack of obstruction to solving $J(F,G)=1$ for $G$.

This is Lemma 3.6 in the reference.

NB: no comments on the rest of the paper.